# Not getting Intellisense from a webpack module in VS Code

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am building a javascript library using NPM and webpack but can't seem to get intellisense to work on my exported module. At the bottom of this post I have included a link to a zip of a small demo project that depicts the problem. Specifically I have a SimulatedClient.js file which imports my module from the dist folder. If you try to use the module it works as intended and has all of the data it should, but you don't get any intellisense/autocomplete in VScode, which makes development a nightmare. How can I get vscode to give valid autocomplete for my module output? Thanks for your help and here is my current webpack setup which is also included in the attached zip:

```
module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: { vueStyles: "./src/js/vueStyles.js" },
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        library: "vueStyles",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        globalObject: "this",
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
            },
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new ProgressBarPlugin({
            format: "  vueStyles webpack [:bar] " + chalk.green.bold(":percent") + " (:elapsed seconds): :msg",
            clear: false,
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|s?c)ss$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/i,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
                            "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|ttf|eot|woff2?)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

[Test Solution Zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfza4kt77z0ghpt/vueStylesTest.zip?dl=0)